# Will prolonged expose to IPA damage uncured prints?

Tags: cleaning

If I leave an uncured resin print in an IPA cleaning tank for too long (For example, if I forget to take it out and leave it in over night) will this damage the print?

I'm using Elegoo gray.

Answer (score 0):

EN
Parts start to get tacky when the resin concentration is 5-10% in the IPA tank. It is advisable to shake the pieces for several seconds. In this way the solvent goes well in all the interstices. Then let the object soak for a few more minutes.
We can repeat the action a second time before leaving a longer drying.

---

FR
Les pièces commencent à devenir poisseuses lorsque la concentration en résine est à 5-10 % dans le bac à IPA. Il est conseillée de d'agitais plusieurs secondes la piéces. De cette manière le solvant va bien dans tous les interstices. On laisse ensuite tremper l’objet encore quelques minutes.
On peut refaire l'action une deuxième fois avant de laisser un séchages plus long.

Comment: I was more wondering if it might cause discoloration or pitting on the surface.

Comment: Well, if it gets sticky, the room loses its cleanliness. And that damages the parts. If the pieces have to be pretty, it's better not to soak in it, it's not made for that!

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Et bien si ca deviens poisseus , la piéces pert en propreté. Et ca détériore la piéces. Si il faut que la piéces soit jolie , mieux vaut pas laisser tremper dedans, ce n'est pas fait pour ça!